# Getting an error passing a php array variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to pass an array and the value of the input from a form to a javascript function.
`$quotes` is an array of posts.

```
<form method="post">
    <p>Search:<input type="text" name="qSearch" id="qSearch" 
      size="40" value="" /></p>
    <button type="button" onClick='searchQuotes(<?php echo json_encode($quotes); ?>, <?php echo json_encode($_POST["qSearch"]); ?>)'>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I get the error on the console: `(index):252 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
Clicking on that takes me to the generated HTML code, which is:

```
<button type="button" onClick='searchQuotes([{"image":{"ID":9990,"Title-height":308}},"keywords":["General Leadership"]], "hats");'>
```

with a red carat underneath the last `>`

It looks like it's encoding the array correctly, but I can't get rid of this error. This is driving me bonkers!  Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of your `searchQuotes(...` onclick function

Comment: Like @Darren said... also `}}, "keywords":[` is the beginning of invalid JSON. You close off the Object before `"keywords":`, which would need to be in an Object, but is not now.

Comment: @Darren, that was a copy and paste error, it's actually in the real code.  I fixed it in the example above.  Still having the same error.

Comment: @StackSlave, I'm passing two things into the function - the first variable an array with two items, the first being an object `(image)` that has two objects `(ID and TItle-height)` and then an array of keywords, and then the second variable is a string `(hats)`. And this is just how the `json_encode` encodes my variable `quotes`. So is there another way to pass this PHP variable to the js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting the PHP variable into a javascript variable and then using it in my code rather than passing it to the function.  That meant I had to keep the script on the page rather than in another file, but it worked.  For some reason it just didn't like how I was passing it. (What I am passing is just a string, so there were no issues with that).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchQuotes(keyword) {
       var quote_array = <?php echo json_encode($quotes); ?>;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your parameter format

Please refer to my code:

```
<?php
$quotes = [
    [
        'name' => 'davis',
        'age' => 18
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'davis',
        'age' => 18
    ]
];
$_POST["qSearch"] = [
    [
        'name' => 'davis',
        'age' => 18
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'davis',
        'age' => 18
    ]
];
?>
<form method="post">
    <p>Search:<input type="text" name="qSearch" id="qSearch"
                     size="40" value="" /></p>

    <button type="button" onClick=searchQuotes({images:'<?php echo json_encode($quotes) ?>',keywords:'<?php echo json_encode($_POST['qSearch']) ?>',hats:'hats'}) >Submit</button>

</form>
```

js code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchQuotes(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

</script>
```

view code, No error!

```
<button type="button" onClick=searchQuotes({images:'[{"name":"davis","age":18},{"name":"davis","age":18}]',keywords:'[{"name":"davis","age":18},{"name":"davis","age":18}]',hats:'hats'}) >Submit</button>
```

Comment: [my console log](https://i.ibb.co/ZH1vSkB/20210122083450.png), Update your code?